# Python Dictionaries stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

hope you are having a nice day, so I need to write a code that takes an input, which is going to be a key in an already existing dictionary, and prints the value as a str as described in the pic. I am stuck rn, I am a beginner and tried everything I see on the web related, appriciate any help, thank you.

[and these are the codes I tried[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtWnl.png)

```py
def read_dataset(filename):
    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    lines_splitted = [line.strip().split(',') for line in lines]
    return {lst[0]: lst[1:] for lst in lines_splitted}
   
movie_dict = read_dataset('dataset.txt')
# DO_NOT_EDIT_ANYTHING_ABOVE_THIS_LINE
    
hey = input('Enter a movie name: ')
actors = movie_dict[hey]
    
    
    
# DO_NOT_EDIT_ANYTHING_BELOW_THIS_LINE
print(','.join(sorted(actors)))
```

[So this is my assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iXxv.png)

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself, rather than linking to an image or posting unformatted code as a comment. It might help if you first read [ask] as well as [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Saying that you are "stuck" and leaving it at that is not very informative.

Comment: @JohnColeman hey I just edited the code, sorry I am new to this site, couldn't figure out at the beginning.

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but the code as edited is not formatted correctly (which is crucial in Python since indentation is important). What you need to do is to figure out how to use the code formatting tool in the question edit box. Also -- what have you tried? It only seems like you yourself have only written 2 lines of code in the posted code. If that is all you did, then you have certainly not "tried everything".

Answer (score 0):

If you begin, try using pandas to make a dataframe of your base. It will be easier to use, and you should reuse it in a lot of cases.

Here an example of what you could do. If you don't understand a point, do not hesitate to ask me:

```
# import the package
import pandas as pd
# build the dataframe for the example
film = pd.DataFrame({'film':['Goldorak','Mickey Mouse'],'actors':[['Actarus','Alkor'],['Mickey, Minnie, Pluto, Goofy']]})

# the input
query = input('Enter the film')

# the 'search' engine
if len(film[film.film==query].actors)>0:
    print(film[film.film==query].actors)
else:
    print('not found in base')
```

EDIT with Dictionary :

```
FILM = {'Forest Gump':['Tom Hanks', 'Gary Sinise']}
query = None
query = input('Enter the film')

try:
    print(FILM.get(query))
except:
    pass
```

Comment: so the dictionary was already written and it is forbidden for me to edit that, and the dictionary is formatted like this : ['Forrest Gump': ['Tom Hanks' , 'Gary Sinise'], so what for example when I enter an input 'Forrest Gump' output should be:  Tom Hanks , Gary Sinise                                                                                                          but I cant find a way to use indexing operator properly, it usually gives a key error